# Получение событий подключения устройств через udev monitor

Tags: rust, udev

Требуется реализовать получение события отключения и подключения Input устройств используя udev monitor.

**Код:**

```
if let Ok(context) = libudev::Context::new() {

            if let Ok(mut monitor) = libudev::Monitor::new(&context){

                if let Err(e) = monitor.match_subsystem("input") {
                    return Err(X::err_init_match_udev(e));
                }

                if let Ok(mut listen) = monitor.listen(){
                    loop {
                        //let mut unique = Vec::new();
                        //println!("CIKLE");
                        for device in listen.receive_event() {
                            let mut path = device.syspath();
                            println!("found device: {:?} is_dir:{}, is_file:{}, exists:{}", path, path.is_dir(), path.is_file(), path.exists());

                            input.recreate_all_device();

                        }
                    }
                    return Ok(());  
                }
                return Err(X::err_init_monitor_listen_udev);
            }
            return Err(X::err_init_monitor_udev);
        }
        Err(X::err_init_context_udev)
```

**Проблема: 1.** Приходит множество событий место 1, отключено или подключено.

**Проблема: 2.** Поток совершенно не блокируется, поток впадает в вечный цикл.

**Зависимости:** libudev https://docs.rs/libudev/0.2.0/libudev/

Comment: Вечный цикл из-за того, что внутри `loop{ for device ... }` нет ни `break`, ни `return`.

Comment: Из [документации к `receive_event`](https://docs.rs/libudev/0.2.0/libudev/struct.MonitorSocket.html#method.receive_event): "This method does not block". Этот метод не блокирующий. Он немедленно возвращает `None`, если нет событий.

Comment: Вот я и задал вопрос, как его сделать блокирующим:) Проблемы есть? есть. какие? описано.